# Sending multiple goutte requests asynchronously

Tags: php, guzzle, goutte

This is the code I am using

```
require_once 'goutte.phar';
use Goutte\Client;
$client = new Client();
for($i=0;$i<10;$i++){
     $crawler = $client->request('GET', 'http://website.com');
     echo '<p>'.$crawler->filterXpath('//meta[@property="og:description"]')->attr('content').'</p>';
     echo '<p>'.$crawler->filter('title')->text().'</p>';
}
```

This works but takes a lot of time to process? Is there any way to do it faster.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For starters, there is nothing asynchronous about your code sample.  Which means that your application will sequentially, perform a get request, wait for the response, parse the response and then loop back.

While Goutte uses Guzzle internally, it does not make use of Guzzles asynchronous capabilities.

To truly make your code asynchronous you will want to refer to the Guzzle Documentation on:

- [Sending Requests within a Pool](http://guzzle.readthedocs.org/en/latest/clients.html#sending-requests-with-a-pool)
- [Asynchronous Response Handling](http://guzzle.readthedocs.org/en/latest/clients.html#asynchronous-response-handling)

Your code sample above would result in something like:

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php' //assuming composer package management.

$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();

$requests = [
    $client->createRequest('GET', $url1),
    $client->createRequest('GET', $url2),
    $client->createRequest('GET', $url3),
    $client->createRequest('GET', $url4),
    $client->createRequest('GET', $url5),
    $client->createRequest('GET', $url6),
    $client->createRequest('GET', $url7),
    $client->createRequest('GET', $url8),
    $client->createRequest('GET', $url9),
    $client->createRequest('GET', $url10),  
];

$options = [
    'complete' => [
        [
            'fn' => function (CompleteEvent $event) {
                $crawler = new Symfony\Component\DomCrawler\Crawler(null, $event->getRequest()->getUrl());
                $crawler->addContent($event->getResponse->getBody(), $event->getResponse()->getHeader('Content-Type'));
                echo '<p>'.$crawler->filterXpath('//meta[@property="og:description"]')->attr('content').'</p>';
                echo '<p>'.$crawler->filter('title')->text().'</p>';
            },
            'priority' => 0,    // Optional
            'once'     => false // Optional
        ]
    ]
];

$pool = new GuzzleHttp\Pool($client, $requests, $options);

$pool->wait();
```

Comment: Hey Shaun, Thank you for the explanation. I get ` Uncaught exception 'InvalidArgumentException' with message` error with this code though.

Comment: @PriyaRawat - Its not fair or reasonable to ask me to troubleshoot an error like the one described when you provide as little information as what has been provided.  Having said that, I would venture a guess that you are trying to use the version of Guzzle that comes with Goutte.  Depending on which version of Goutte you are using you (likely) will not have the right version of Guzzle.  Ensure that your composer.json file lists guzzlehttp\guzzle and symfony\dom-crawler.